# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied while trying access with another user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, access-denied

I am getting above error while trying to access s3 through another user, Below is bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxbucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAll",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1111111111:user/xxx_user"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxbucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxbucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Command Used:
aws s3 ls s3://xxxxbucket

Can somebody please help with this issue

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance that you have the `Requester pays` option enabled on the bucket?  I've blown a whole day on a matter like this.  Even if I opened the bucket up completely, allowing any access, it seems that `Requester pays` attribute was blocking access.

It makes sense, of course, though I don't fully understand the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 0):

That policy looks like it should work - have you considered testing it using the IAM Policy Simulator at https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/

It should allow you to test your policy and user and confirm that it's setup correctly (or if not, give you more information about why access is being denied - it may be due to another policy you have somewhere in your account).